# Find lines in a text file containing a list of strings, save matching lines to text file

Tags: python

I am trying to make a script that gets all lines from one file, finds lines in a second file that contain any string from the first file, and print all matching lines into a third file. My code looks like this, but it doesnt print anything. Im not too experienced in python, so i might be missing something obvious.

```
def count():
    namecount = 0
    with open("emailusernames.txt") as f:
            for namecount, l in enumerate(f):
                pass
            namecount = namecount + 1


    return namecount


def main():
    with open("emailusernames.txt") as file_in:
        lines = []
    for line in file_in:
        lines.append(line)
    for line in lines:
        if username in line:
            print(line)
```

Comment: If this is all the code, you're never calling either of the functions. You need to call them for them to run.

Comment: The first `for line in file_in` loop consumes all the input.  There is no input remaining for the second loop, so it never runs.  Perhaps you meant the second loop to be `for line in lines`?

Comment: The file is also closed before it's read.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes, fixed that, still doesnt work

Comment: If you fixed it, then post the updated code.